# Противоречивый текст про репорт проблем с регистрацией на мете, учитывая, что для публикации на мете нужна регистрация

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, статус-завершено, контактная-форма

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact

Выбрать "Другое", покажут текст:

> Пожалуйста, помните, что любые технические проблемы, будь то **ошибка
>   завершения регистрации** или дефект на сайте **лучше публиковать
>   напрямую на Мете**, где ответ вы получите много быстрее. Дополнительно
>   для связи с управляющим сообщества по не конфиденциальным вопросам вы
>   можете воспользоваться чатом сообщества.

Но для того, чтоб иметь возможность писать на мете, нужно зарегистрироваться.

Comment: Этот текст показывается всегда. Не надо выбирать "Другое".

Comment: Ух, и то верно.

Comment: Эх.. А скриншот?

Comment: @Qwertiy поздно, выкатили уже :D

Comment: @Suvitruf, ну так надо ж стразу скриншотить)

Comment: @Qwertiy тогда ведь смогут поймать с поличным!

Comment: @Qwertiy новую метку придумали? )

Comment: @Suvitruf, вот так вот отвлекаться на написание комментов во время редактирования меток)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот к чему приводит добавление излишней смысловой нагрузки при [переводе](https://ru.traducir.win/string/7425):

> [image: transifex]

Скриншот из Transifex, т.к. в tradicir'е переноса строк нет. Утвердил перевод без чрезмерного смысла.

> Пожалуйста, опишите вашу проблему

Вероятно, это была такая попытка минимизировать разбор заявок, перенаправив задающих на Мету, где помимо редких сотрудников компании будут отвечать толпы специально обученных волонтёров.

Comment: На SOen в этой форме вообще текста нет: https://stackoverflow.com/contact

Comment: @Suvitruf так "Please describe your problem" же!

Comment: Слона то я и не приметил.